# How to find index of element with minimum value?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

Say I have a list `val list = List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).`

Now how do I find the index of the minimum element of the list (e.g. 1 in this case)?

Comment: Is it a homework. I think it is too easy to do

Comment: It's an extremely simple homework problem.

Comment: @vodkhang and @Odrade, I graduated 10 years go. They didn't teach us functional programming in our university. Hence such homework-sounding questions. :(

Comment: But, it is a normal loop? You just have a variable store the current minimum and then loop over the loop. It is nothing special about functional programming or at least you can solve it with OOP or procedure programming, am I missing something?

Comment: @vodkhang, I am learning to do things functionally.

Comment: in that case, that's ok. Because I think you just want to get the index of the minimum.:)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On Scala 2.8:

```
List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).zipWithIndex.min._2
```

Answer (score 7):

I suppose the easiest way is `list.indexOf(list.min)`. It will throw an exception when the list is empty, although so will Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 6):

An empty list has no minimal value. A list of only one element has that element as its minimum. For all other lists the minimum is either the first element of that list or the minimum of the rest of the list, depending on which is greater.

So to find the index this becomes: For a list of length 1 the index of the minimum is 0. If the list has more than one element and the minimum of the tail is greater than the head, it's also 0. If the head is greater then the index is the index of the minimum of the tail plus one.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, a slightly safer solution (which handles empty lists) would consist in using [`minOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#minOption%5BB%3E:A%5D(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering%5BB%5D):Option%5BA%5D)/`maxOption` which returns `None` if the sequence is empty:

```
List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).zipWithIndex.minOption.map(_._2)
// Option[Int] = Some(1)
List[Int]().zipWithIndex.minOption.map(_._2)
// Option[Int] = None
```

This way you could also decide to fallback on a default value when the list is empty:

```
List(34, 11, 98, 56, 43).zipWithIndex.minOption.map(_._2).getOrElse(-1)
// Int = 1
List[Int]().zipWithIndex.minOption.map(_._2).getOrElse(-1)
// Int = -1
```